# Empty parent menu item

Tags: 7, navigation

I have created a new content type on Drupal and I chose it will be available in which menus. But when I add a content for my new content type and after I check the "Provide a menu link" checkbox, the "Parent item" select list becomes empty after it was populated.

[image]

And this is caused by an ajax query that gets executed after checking the "Provide a menu link" checkbox.

[image]

And this query return an empty array.